# why does if statement not work in actionlistener

Tags: java, if-statement

```
enter.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            User = input.getText();

            if (User == "hello") {
                Console = "Hi User!";
            }

            output.setText("User: " + User + "\n" + "Console: " + Console);
        }
    });
```

When I run it, it displays the text on the GUI.
But why is it that the console doesn't respond.
I did a system.out.prinln on User when I wrote "hello"
Thats exactly hat it said, why is this if statement not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to compare String using `.equals` method not `==`, so try to change you code to something like:

```
if (User.equals("hello")) {
    Console = "Hi User!";
}
```

Read more about [How to Compare String in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)